# How to Bind table data to chart?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, data-binding, charts, bind

Actually i have more than 10 columns....in designing form i have 2 dropdownlist and 2 textboxes..

1-Dropdownlist-for select the state
2-Dropdownlist -for choose the column name like temperature, sea level,etc..
3-textbox-for select start date 
4-textbox-for select end date

Now i wanna generate chart for this functions...whenever i choose the state and temperature and start date and end date i need to generate chart for this process.

I wanna shows details in chart in between date from start date to end date...

i wanna generate chart for my passing parameters like... i choose state as California and temperature and  choose the start date as well as end date(i.e start date 25/08/12 and end date 01/01/13)...now i want to create chart for given input....

in my database table i have 5 fields like state,temp,sealevel,snow,date....

Pls any one give ur idea for this process....

Comment: what are you using for charts and what version of VS are you running (if it is VS)

Comment: visual studio 2008 sir....

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this can be an answer, but ill type you here what i would do in VS 2012.

If you want to make a generic representation, and not 3( temp,sealevel,snow) charts ,then you need to represent values with same format/data type. There is ChartControl for VS 2010 that comes preinstalled with vs2012, but i do not have a clue if there is anything free for VS2008.

This is link showing you  ChartControl.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456632.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.aspx

Now i would say that doesn't help you alot, but you should check for some solutions for VS2008. I know few solutions that are paid, but i dont know if that is an option for you.